# Vibrate API not working on pageload

Tags: javascript, mobile

The following code isn't working...

```
function onPageLoad(){
    navigator.vibrate([500]);}
```

Testing it on mobile device, when I attach to a button it works but not onload????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you want to execute any javascript code you need to write it to javascript `onload` method

```
window.onload = function() {
  navigator.vibrate([500]);
};
```

or you can attach your function to body element onload event,

```
 <body onload="onPageLoad()">
```

Comment: I am using <body onload="onPageLoad()"> but the vibrate only happens the first time you go to the page, I even put an alert box call under the vibrate call and the alert box fires every time, but no vibrate.

Comment: @user1724365 you need to add event listener where you wish to vibrate, i.e. on button click